# How can I convert IEnumerable<object> to List<IFoo> where each object is an IFoo?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

How can I convert `IEnumerable<object>` to `List<IFoo>` where each object is an `IFoo`?

I have an `IEnumerable<object>`, `someCollection`, and each item in `someCollection` is an `IFoo` instance.  How can I convert `someCollection` into a `List<IFoo>`? Can I use convert or cast or something instead of looping through and building up a list?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can use [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) to cast the items, and use [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261) to get a list.

Try:

```
 IEnumerable<object> someCollection; //Some enumerable of object.
 var list = someCollection.Cast<IFoo>().ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ Cast and ToList *IS* looping and building up a list; it's just hidden. Answer is really there is no way to do this without a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
enumerable.Cast<IFoo>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

`someCollection.Cast<IFoo>().ToList()`