# How to perform LINQ on IEnumerable<Employee> / IEnumerable<object>?

Tags: c#

I have

```
IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
{
  return Get<IEmployeeRepository>().GetAll();
}
```

Where **IEmployeeRepository** is

```
public interface IEmployeeRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll();  
    }
```

**Employee.cs** is as under

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }        
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I want to perform a search on the records obtained from **GetAllEmployees()** based on the EmployeeId passed. Like as under

```
public void SearchEmployee(int empId)
        {
            var empRecords = this.GetAllEmployees();
            var filteredRecords = empRecords.
        }
```

[image]

I actually looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855836/how-can-i-convert-ienumerableobject-to-listifoo-where-each-object-is-an-ifoo) answer but could not fit into the requirement.
What I need to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757365/does-linq-work-with-ienumerable

Comment: Might be you are missing namespace declaration on top `using System.Linq`. Also keep in mind `IEnumerable` does not support differed execution like `IQuerable`

Comment: What happens if you change `var empRecords = this.GetAllEmployees();` to `IEnumerable<Employee> empRecords = this.GetAllEmployees();` ?

Comment: @Jenish Rabadiya, Excellent. I just saw that in my namespace.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya What do you mean by *IEnumerable does not support differed execution like IQuerable*. `IEnumerable` do supports deferred execution. In fact `Enumerable.Where`, `Select` etc are lazy.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, you are right. I might used wrong word there. I was meant to say it does not support linq to sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out that the namespace **System.Linq is missing.**
Else we could even do

```
foreach (var item in empRecords)
{
   //
}
```

I will give the credit to @ Jenish Rabadiya, though others have also given correct opinion.

Comment: Didn't Jenish Rabadiya figure this out?

Comment: I have already mentioned that (:. And given the credit to him. (:

Comment: I think Jenish should answer it and then he will get the "credit" he deserves ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is the object first you need to convert to list of object and then try to cast it.

```
 (empRecords as IEnumerable<object>).Cast(....)
```